# Есть ли ошибка в приводимом предложении (см.)?

Tags: грамматика

Что неправильно в предложении:

"Бабушка переехала в другой город, когда ей было 10 лет".

Как можно заменить вторую часть предложения? Помогите сформулировать правильно. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильна логика. Она не была бабушкой, когда её было 10 лет. Но вопрос действительно больше из области ребусов, чем языка.

> Бабушка переехала в другой город, когда была девочкой 10 лет.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, ваш учитель обладает крайне редким,специфическим и извращенным вкусом на построение предложений и яростно навязывает этот вкус. В этом предложении нет абсолютно ничего неправильного.

Answer (score 1):

В предложении нет грамматических ошибок, но *не во всяком контексте* оно безупречно *стилистически*. Последовательность его частей такова, что акцентируется *время* переезда, в то время как *факт переезда* выглядит само собой разумеющимся или известным из предшествующей фразы, например, такой:

> У моей бабушки с детства была непереносимость влажного тропического
> климата, и ей с родителями пришлось покинуть родной Рио. Бабушка
> переехала в другой город, когда ей было десять лет.

Однако *вне контекста* предложение не воспринимается как самостоятельное, законченное сообщение - из-за имеющегося **порядка слов**. Чтобы сделать его *нейтральным* (без акцента на время), можно
этот порядок изменить:

> Когда бабушке было десять лет, она переехала в другой город.